Django admin: display of fields depending on the model
I am developing a backend for a landing page type site, and during the development of the project I came across a lot of models
...the rest of the code
class FunctionalBlock(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    icon = models.ForeignKey(to='Image', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,related_name='function_block_icon')
    image = models.ForeignKey(to='Image', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,related_name='function_block_image')
    form = models.ForeignKey(to='FormNVA', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,related_name='function_block')
    buttons = models.ManyToManyField(to='Buttons',blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    section = models.ForeignKey(to='Section', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='function_block')
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
class Section(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    background = models.ForeignKey(to='Image', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,related_name='section')

# PAGE
class PageHome(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey(to='Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    head = models.OneToOneField(to='Head', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.OneToOneField(to='Body', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='page_home')

    objects = models.Manager()
    objects_lang = LanguageManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

class PageServices(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey(to='Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    head = models.OneToOneField(to='Head', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.OneToOneField(to='Body', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='page_services')


    objects = models.Manager()
    objects_lang = LanguageManager()

class PageCareer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey(to='Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    head = models.OneToOneField(to='Head', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.OneToOneField(to='Body', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='page_career')


    objects = models.Manager()
    objects_lang = LanguageManager()

# BODY

class Body(models.Model):


    class FieldSets(Enum):
        HOME =['services','options','become_part_of_us','cta_text','numbers','partners','questions']
        SERVICES = ['services']

    # Home
    services = models.ForeignKey(to='Section',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='body_home_services')
    options = models.ForeignKey(to='Section',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='body_home_options')
    become_part_of_us = models.ForeignKey(to='Section',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='body_home_become_part_of_us')
    cta_text = models.ForeignKey(to='Section',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='body_home_cta_text')
    numbers = models.ForeignKey(to='Section',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='body_home_numbers')
    partners = models.ForeignKey(to='Section',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='body_home_partners')
    questions = models.ForeignKey(to='Section',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='body_home_questions')
    # Services
    news = models.ForeignKey(to='Section',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='body_home_news')

as you can see I have a separate model for each page, similarly I had a separate Body Model for each page model and to have them reduce I have summarized the fields in one table namely body and here I am facing a problem which is when I create any page in admin panel I want to filter the fields specifically related to this page model when I click on add body in the admin panel and a popup appears
ADMIN PANEL
as a solution I looked at passing url params and using get_fieldsets to filter the fields but I couldn't achieve what I wanted.
@admin.register(Body)
class BodyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj):
        model = self.model
        related_model = self.opts.related_objects[0].related_model
        fieldsets = copy.deepcopy(super().get_fieldsets(request, obj))

        if related_model is PageHome:
             fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] = model.FieldSets.HOME.value
        if related_model is PageServices:
            fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] = model.FieldSets.SERVICES.value

        return fieldsets


Is my approach to creating a backend for the landing page correct and if so, is it possible to achieve field filtering in the body?
thanks in advance
I tried passing query params to solve this problem, I also looked for a dependency in BodyAdmin to the calling Page...Admin but these two options were unsuccessful

I think this fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] = model.FieldSets.HOME.value  and fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] = model.FieldSets.SERVICES.value should work just fine, can you verify related_model is what you expect it to be?
try to print model.FieldSets.HOME.value before the if related_model is PageHome: and/or inside it, just to debug where is the problem.
I think BodyAdmin doesn't know what page type you're coming from, which means you may need to pass a parameter to the popup page, then in BodyAdmin.get_fieldsets() you handle that passed parameter.
I'm not sure, but I think you may need to modify the URL parameters by overriding ForeignKeyRawIdWidget.url_parameters() in django.contrib.admin.widgets
As for your models structure, I think it might be improved.
Since PageHome, PageService, and PageCareer are similar and have the exact same fields, then why don't you use one model with extra field to differentiate the page type. then use the proxy feature with a custom manager for each one, like the following:
Create your managers:
# Base manager
class PageManager(models.Manager):
    class PageType(models.TextChoices):
        HOME = 'H', _('Home')
        SERVICE = 'S', _('Service')
        CAREER = 'C', _('Career')

    # default page type
    PAGE_TYPE = PageType.SERVICE

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(type=self.PAGE_TYPE)
        )

# Page managers
class PageHomeManager(PageManager):
    PAGE_TYPE = PageManager.PageType.HOME

class PageServiceManager(PageManager):
    PAGE_TYPE = PageManager.PageType.SERVICE

class PageCareerManager(PageManager):
    PAGE_TYPE = PageManager.PageType.CAREER

and as for your models:
# Models
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PageManager.PageType.choices, default=PageManager.PAGE_TYPE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(to='Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    head = models.OneToOneField(to='Head', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.OneToOneField(to='Body', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='page_home')

    objects = PageManager()
    objects_lang = LanguageManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.type = self.default_type if self.default_type else self.type
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


class PageHome(Page):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = PageHomeManager()
    default_type = PageHomeManager.PAGE_TYPE

class PageServices(Page):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = PageServiceManager()
    default_type = PageServiceManager.PAGE_TYPE

class PageCareer(Page):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = PageCareerManager()
    default_type = PageCareerManager.PAGE_TYPE

Then you can use PageHome, PageService, and PageCareer the way you used to. Because they will act like a standalone model with their own table and fields, but in fact they're not. They use the Page model with a custom filter.
Hope it helps
